# Changing min/max for Symfony2 range validator at runtime

Tags: symfony, range, validation

I need to change the max value for the range validator in Symfony at runtime, while building the form with FormBuilder. Has anybody an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Well, Symfony is designed so that the constraints are attached to the underlying object/data, not the form (type) itself.

However, you *can* add constraints directly to the form if the form is not mapped to a class.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation

Basically, you can define a `constraints` option in the form builder which should be an array of constraint objects.

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range;

```
$builder->add('your_field', null, array(
    new Assert\Range(array(
        'min'        => 10
      , 'max'        => $someDyanmicValue
      , 'minMessage' => 'min error message'
      , 'maxMessage' => 'max error message'
    ))
));
```

If your form *is* mapped to a class where the Range constraint is defined, you'll have to go about this a different way. Let me know.

Comment: My Form is mappend to a class, and I'll keep it that way. But I found another possible solution using an event listener for the form. Thx anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @amigian74 If you have found another solution please share them with us. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote before in my comment I used a solution like this:

```
first part of the range:

class Entity {
 //@Assert\NotBlank()
 private $property;
}

second part of the range:

$formBuilder->get('property')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function(FormEvent $event) use ($something) {
        $property = $event->getForm()->getData();
        if ($property > $something) {
            $event->getForm()->addError(new FormError(...));
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this was helpful